# Call function defined in isolated scope in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Am I missing something here?

Shouldn't I be able to access the function `showHelp()` from the template `ng-click` ?

I've been fighting with this for hours and I can't get it right

```
angular.module('starter.directives', [])
.directive('errorMessage', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^form',
    scope: true,
    template:'<button ng-click="showHelp()" class="button icon ion-android-alert button-outline button-assertive"></button>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {

      scope.showHelp = function(){
        console.log('hello');
      }

    }
  };
});
```

Comment: it would work as intended? **Side Note** you have prototypically inherited scope not an isolated scope.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your code.  I am guessing you just forgot to include the module in your HTML.  Something that looks like

```
<div ng-app="starter.directives">
    ....
</div>
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/7ze30y7j/2/) your code that is working properly in jsFiddle

Comment: I'm so ashamed, I was putting the ``<error-message></error-message>`` inside a label, so the ng-click wasn't firing

Answer (score 0):

You should add it in `controller` not `link` function. `link` function runs **after** everything was rendered.

```
angular.module('starter.directives').directive('errorMessage', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    template:'<button ng-click="showHelp()" class="button icon ion-android-alert button-outline button-assertive">Test</button>',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.showHelp = function(){
        console.log('hello');
      }
    }
  };
});
```

I think the problem is that you reinitialize your module by passing `[]` here
`angular.module('starter.directives', [])` If you pass a second parameter to angular.module, it would think that you pass an array of dependecies and will reinit the module.

Comment: I don't want to add it on every controller, since it will be view-dependant and not controller dependant, if that makes sense.

Comment: I ment directive's controller. But anyway it should work even in link function, I just tried it in jsfiddle.

Comment: I'm so ashamed, I was putting the ``<error-message></error-message>`` inside a label, so the ng-click wasn't firing